# Reference to 'FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded' is ambiguous

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was building listener to read the data in Firebase, suddenly I started getting this error. I don't understand why am I getting below error.

> Reference to 'FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded' is ambiguous

Below is code.

```
- (void) setObserverForMessageAdded {

_refHandle = [[self senderMessageNode] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
    NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;
    NSLog(@"%@",postDict);

}];
}
```

Comment: Please post your codes instead of screenshots

Comment: Try this : 1. Clean the project
2. Deleting everything inside '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/' (the button inside the organizer window did not work for me)
3. Clean once more
4. Build project

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the derived data helped me to solve this problem. It seems to be odd index problem. I cleared using the code below on Terminal.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```